# why is toString() returning a "/" to my String path?

Tags: java

I have a `toString()` method that is returning a "/" at the beginning of the String, which is a filepath. this is seriously screwing up my program because it's not able to read the resource with that "/" in front:

```
public String toString() {
    return this.value;
  }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated,

Edit:

Here's the constant:

```
DELEGATE_JNDI_NAME("java:/comp/env/jndi/delegates"),
```

Comment: the obvious question is what is `this.value`?

Comment: Can you show us where you're setting the value?

Comment: show us more code. how is "value" populated? where are you showing/using the path and why you are arguing that is the java language that puts the / to the value?

Comment: Your method doesn't have any arguments...

Comment: What happens when you do `System.out.println(this.value)`?

Comment: What is DELEGATE_JNDI_NAME? Is that a method call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing you're trying to pass the `"java:/comp/emv/jndi/delegates"` as an argument to your `toString()` method. I don't see any leading /'s, but if you do get one, use this method to remove it...

```
String removeSlash(String file) {
     char[] letters = file.toCharArray();
     if (file.charAt(0) == '/'){ //first character is '/'
         return file.substring(1);
     } else {
         return file;
     }
}
```

Comment: +1, with the provided information it's the best that can be done! In terms of the leading slash, I assume it's the bit after `java:` that's taken into consideration, leaving /comp/emv...etc.

Comment: @berry120 Yeah, but I'll wait and see what the OP thinks; thanks for the comment! :)

Comment: +1 for responding with little information. Id suggest squishing the f or loop with a substring(1, strlength).

Comment: Blimey what a contraption. `if (file.charAt(0) == '/') return file.substring(1); return file;`

Comment: @EJP You really should just leave a comment instead of downvoting...

Comment: @EJP ...and I'm really not very experienced with Java. :(

Comment: @fireshadow52 I am free to both comment on and downvote your answer, and also to flag it as 'very low quality'. I have done all three.

Comment: @EJP Why is there "something clearly wrong with this post"? It is entirely correct.

Comment: I don't know where that quotation came from and I also don't know what you think downvotes are actually for.

Comment: I'm just asking why you would downvote/flag this answer just because it's inefficient. There may be a faster way but as I said I'm not that experienced and anyway what does the `.charAt()` method do?

Comment: @Second downvoter: I hope you have a good reason for doing this...